# Serve PyQt4 GUIs in Web-Application using HTML/CSS/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, user-interface, widget, pyqt4, pyqtgraph

Currently, we have a number of GUIs that have been developed using PyQt4 and PyQtGraph. 
We need to make these interfaces accessible to a number of remote users and are hoping to do so by serving the GUIs through an HTML/CSS/JavaScript Web-Application.

The link below provides a few suggestions for this task, but these seem to apply to a project that is in its initial stages of creation. I'm familiar with the development of Python-JavaScript Web-Applications using the Pyramid Server and would like to use this same method for providing users access to PyQt4 GUIs that have already been developed.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/109572/can-i-create-a-desktop-python-gui-application-and-run-it-as-a-web-app

So my question is, can I serve a functional PyQt4 GUI as a widget using HTML/CSS/JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is hard. In theory you could use a VNC-like approach that sends an image of the window to the client browser and sends user events back to the server. This will probably have poor interactivity depending on the networking and would require a lot of server power, depending on the number of users. (For an example of this, see: https://github.com/campagnola/webqt)

You're probably better off distributing the application with something like py2exe, py2app, cx_freeze, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I personally haven't tried it but you could look into Wt: http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/

It is a C++ framework that has a Qt flavour. It has a Java version called JWt. Hence, a Jython binding exists for us Python programmers: http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/other_language

It is not a direct replacement of Qt, and  might need modification to your Qt code to work as a Wt web app, but it certainly seems worth it to look into.